# RFID Reader - Nordic ID Stix

Tags: c#, rfid

I have a device called 'Nordic ID Stix'.
But i dont really know how can i read from it!

Of course first i try using

```
System.IO.Ports.SerialPort
```

but it dont work.
(I cant start reading when antenna is turn off... )

Device is working and read rfid (i using AnyReader to read codes and it was work)
But now i need to write some software to reading from RFID.
I tried to use:

- Phidget
- System.IO.Ports.SerialPort

and now i want to try a :

```
Microsoft.SensorServices.Rfid.Utilities
```

but i cant find it anywhere in VisualStudio 2013 or anything else.

Please help me.

P.S. I find very much 'tutorials' which redirects to a blank page... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need the SDK (NurDistribution) that you can download from their extranet page (login required), or you will send the email to Nordic ID support (support@nordicid.com).